# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int' when printing

Tags: python

I am trying to perform feature selection on a set of dummy columns. Column types include: non-null uint8, non-null int32. My target column has values 0 and 1.

my code looks like this:

```
print("Num Features: %d") % features_
print("Selected Features: %s") % support_
print("Feature Ranking: %s") % ranking_
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using python3.x, you can use fstrings?

```
print(f'Num Features: {fit.n_features_}')
print(f'Selected Features: {fit.support_}')
print(f'Feature Ranking: {fit.ranking_}')
```

Comment: This may solve the issue, but it doesn't go any distance to addressing the question

Answer (score 3):

To actually answer your question, it's because you're using the `%` operator outside the `print` function (which returns `None` as the error message says) but the `%` operator is a string operator. You need

```
print("Num Features: %d" % features_)
print("Selected Features: %s" % support_)
print("Feature Ranking: %s" % ranking_)
```

But yes, f-strings and `str.format` are preferred to `%` these days.